# Beamer will not display the logo

Tags: beamer, logos

My pdf does not display the logo on any slide.

```
  \documentclass[12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


  \usetheme{Goettingen}
  \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{ucs}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{graphicx}


  \begin{document}
     \logo{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{logo}}

  \begin{frame}
     \titlepage
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
     \frametitle{frame}

     \begin{itemize}
        \item
     \end{itemize}

  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position where the logo is inserted is decided by the theme used, `Goettingen` here. So you can't specify its position. As a work around you can use `\insertlogo` in

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertlogo}
```

Code:

```
  \documentclass[12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertlogo}


  \usetheme{Goettingen}
  \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{ucs}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
   \logo{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{logo}}
  \begin{document}


  \begin{frame}
     \titlepage
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
     \frametitle{frame}

     \begin{itemize}
        \item
     \end{itemize}

  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
```

[image]